# In a laptop cooling fan, what are the grills (for air flow) called? And what's heat sink?

Tags: laptop, heatsink, fan

My laptop's cooling fan is pretty much identical to this:

[image: Laptop cooling fan]

*([Image credit](http://www.laptopaid.com/product-type/laptop-replacement-parts/fans/sony-vaio-vpcea2-series-fan-plus-cooling-heatsink-udqfrzh14cf0-laptop-tested.html))*

As detailed in the question, I would like to know what the grills on the side of the fan, which enable hot air flow out of the laptop, are called. Is it called ventilator or something (on the whole)?

And what's heat sink?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The copper square is the heat sink base. The copper tube is a [**heat pipe**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_pipe). The black metal sheets are [**fins**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fin_%28extended_surface%29). The whole thing, including the fan, is the heat sink.

Comment: The whole thing including the fan is the cooler and not the heat sink. Cooler in this case consists of two parts: the heat sink and the fan. And the heat sink design in this case is the heat pipe design. Heat sink base collects the heat from CPU and distribute the heat via the heat pipe (capillary effect allows faster heat exchange and heat transportation) to fins (radiator) where cool airflow throws the heat out

Answer (score 2):

The whole device is the Heat Sink Fan.

The fan, is the thing in the center obviously.

The *grills* are the radiator fins.

The copper square sits on the CPU, above thermal paste which fills the gaps between the CPU and the Heatsink. The copper is also the *heat pipe* which takes the heat to the radiator which then has the fan and fins to help dissipate the heat and expel it from the laptop chassis.

Comment: You said, _"The copper square sits on the CPU, above thermal paste which fills the gaps between the CPU and the Heatsink."_ -- I opened up my laptop the other day, and all I had to do remove the Heat Sink Fan is unscrew at various places. There wasn't any while thermal paste. I am a bit worried now, I didn't apply any when assembling my laptop back. :-/

Comment: Thermal paste isn't required if you do what some modders do and polish down the CPU and heat sink base; the thermal paste is only required to fill the small gaps and cracks in both, and the polishing eliminates those.

Comment: No, you still want paste even if you polish. if you where perfect it would squeeze it all out, but if you missed anything the paste covers it.

Answer (score 1):

I’d suggest heat sink only for the square copper part because the function of the strap is to conduct heat to the fan rather than merely to absorb heat. The grill I would term “fins” (any of a number of standing ridges on an ordinarily hot object, as a radiator, a cylinder of an internal-combustion engine, etc., intended to maximize heat transfer)  to the surrounding air by exposing a large surface area" [ref](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fin) or “heat exchange fins”.